# How to specify which Activity Types should trigger notifications to the Assignee

Tags: email, activities

Currently the setting at civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1 (pls don't ask why it is a Display Preference!) is just an On/Off switch.

Looking in to providing an extension so the Activity Types could be specified to include/exclude.

Anyone taken any steps in this direction already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been added to core by the Fuzion team via this [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11222)

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  This is one of the use cases described for [CRM-20638](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20638)  It provides a hook that your extension could use to select which activity types to include/exclude. There is a PR from May waiting for review if you can help with that.

Comment: does aiden == aydun? Was discussing with my daughter gemma about someone she met at civicon - you? anyway on to the topic to hand, yes, happy to have Jitendra work with you on this. Is this ready for me to set him as Assignee to review?

Comment: Yes, that's me - one of the more creative misspellings of my name! Great to meet Gemma at Civicon.  Thanks for having Jitendra look at this - it's  ready for review.